# How to make equals read a character

Tags: java

So what I need help on is that I have this code and I do not know how the if statements can read ",", ".", and "$". I think the String X should be Char instead of String but I do not know how I could change my `String X = in.next();` with `char[] arr = new char[]` and this statement need to be as an input statement! Thank you for helping me and after answering could you write what kinds of things I could do to make my questions better?

So what this code is supposed to do is that for example input is say &&&&&& and 456 then the output is supposed to be*** 456 so meaning &&&&&& = ****** and as many numbers there are meaning length the *'s go away so* * -> ***456
and if input contains "," for example input is &&&,&&&&&(anywhere is fine for ",") and 10000 then output is 10,000 and so on with "." that puts decimal point where it is placed and round up to that point and "$" just puts a dollar sign in front of the numbers

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class printFormatting
    {

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.println("Enter the &'s and ,'s");
         String X = in.next();

         System.out.println("Enter the numbers");
         String Y = in.next();

         int lengthX = X.length();
         int lengthY = Y.length();

         if (X.equals(",") && X.equals("."))
         {
             System.out.println("Works , && .");
             //This is to see if , and . both are being able to be seen by the code
         }
         else if (X.equals(","))
         {
             System.out.println("Works ,");
             //This is to see if , can be seen
         }
         else if (X.equals("."))
         {
             System.out.println("Works ,");
             //same
         }
         if (X.equals("$"))
         {
             System.out.println("Works $");
         }
         for (int z = lengthX-lengthY; z > 0;)
         {
             System.out.print("*");
             z--;
         }
         System.out.println(Y);


     }

 }
```

Comment: [tag:javascript] tag removed. If you don't know the difference between Java and Javascript, you'd best read up on it before you misuse tags again and not get the help you need.

Comment: Next suggestion: Use multiple println statements in your code above to test the values held by your variables to see what your program is doing at each step. Doing this will help you debug your errors. Also as an aside, you'll want to learn and follow Java naming rules, and have all your variable names begin with a lower-case letter and class names begin with an upper-case letter. Like language tags mentioned earlier, following these rules will help others better understand your code and your problem, and get you better help here.

Comment: So after each step I would put like System.out.println(X); etc so it shows what each step does

Comment: Exactly! It's a makeshift debugger.

Comment: Maybe changing "equals" to "contains" could be useful.

Comment: Post it as answer and I will check it for you if you want

Comment: The 'equals' operator doesn't perform input. Please adjust your title to reflect your actual question, whatever it is.

Comment: Um I am solved with my question by rbalent and contains work with my code so thank you for down voting? if that was you